# How to use the IF function to check multiple conditions and get multiple values

Tags: excel-formula

This is to check if orders have been paid on time and alert on status.

I am trying to check for 3 condition combinations from 2 cells to return 3 different values into a single cell.  I am not sure if this is even possible with Excel.

The cells to check would be column E and D, while column C would have 3 different values depending on the condition combination.

Column D would have a set date in which an order was shipped.

Column E would have either “pay” or “not paid” options.

The values to return on column C would be:

“Pending” if the order has been shipped within 30 days and has not been paid

“Late” if the order has been shipped past 30 days and has not been paid.

“paid” if the order shows “paid” in column E

[image: Excel Snip here]

Comment: Shipped within 30 days of what date? Today? You want to override the text "CALL" and replace it with a formula, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple nested IF in cell C3 and copy down. Depending on how you define "within" 30 days, you may want to use `>=30` in the formula below instead of `>30`.

```
=IF(E3="paid",E3,IF(TODAY()-D3>30,"late","pending"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks... that was so simple to do.  I need to have a better understanding of the Excel formula structure so that I can write so nice and clean formulas for excel.